# mxGraph events in C# for desktop application

Tags: c#, mxgraph

I have downloaded samples for C# from mxGraph site. Everything is fine except for mouse events which I can't find in library provided for mxGraph. Are mouse events not available at all or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you specify which "samples for C# from mxGraph site" are you talking about?

Comment: https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/archive/master.zip

Comment: Great. And which part of code you mean specifically? Could you append it to your post?

Comment: What I mean is that if I run the C# sample I get diagrams displayed but if I want to add mouse interaction for selecting and moving objects  I can't find a way to do it.